# Find $\lim_{ ( X, Y) → ( 0 , 0 )}\frac{ Y^2}{ X+Y} $

Tags: limits

I know that this limit does not exist, but I want to know how can I prove it.

**Edit** : I Think I Found the answer :

$\lim_{ ( X, Y) → ( 0 , 0 )}\frac{ Y^2}{ X+Y}$

I Write ${X+Y=U}$ and ${ Y^2=U-X}$

Now I can write $\lim_{ ( x , y ) → ( 0 , 0 )}\frac{ (U-X)^2}{U} $

$\lim_{ ( x , y ) → ( 0 , 0 )}\frac{ X^2}{ x +y} $

Then Solve that with writing ${X}=√U$ to $\frac{U}{U}=1 $

Comment: Hint:  Try to make the denominator very small.  You create a sequence $(x_n, y_n)$ where $|x_n-y_n|$ is much smaller than $y_n^2$.

Comment: Approach the origin along the line $(x,y)=(t,t)$ and then along the curve $(x,y)=(t^2-t,t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the two sequences $(x_n, y_n) = (1/n^2, 1/n)$ and $(x_n,y_n)=(1/n,0)$. What do you observe? What does the definition of the limit imply?

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{y\to0}\lim_{x\to y}\frac{y^2}{x+y}\neq\lim_{x\to0^+}\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y^2}{x+y}$. What does this imply?